# Swift 2: How to calculate the number of days between current iPhone time and date I provide

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdate, swift2

I see a lot of posts but I can't resolve the problem. I need to know how many days/hour/minute elapsed from the date of iPhone and a older date that I provide. I tried different tutorial and post here in stackoverflow but nothing worked. Please help me thank you.

```
class timeElapsed {

init?(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate){

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])

   print(components.day)

return nil

}
```

with this code it works but it gives me 7 days of difference instead of 11 days of difference. In fact the dates are `endDate: 2015-10-07 14:27:53 +0000`   `startDate: 2015-09-26 15:17:55 +0000`

Comment: You need to show how you are converting your date strings to NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
func timeBetween(startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate) -> [Int]
{
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    
    let components = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])
    
    return [components.day, components.hour, components.minute]
}
```

You pass the start and the end date and get returned an array of ints.

### Example:

```
let nowDate:NSDate // current date
let historydate:NSDate // some old date
    
let timeSince:[Int] = timeBetween(historydate, endDate: nowDate)
timeSince[0] // days
timeSince[1] // hours
timeSince[2] // minutes
```

Comment: it says extra argument'endcall' in call in timeSince

Comment: Check your code again, there is no "endcall" argument in my answer

Comment: Thats wierd, Can you paste your code? This code works on my machine.

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use? Your code works on 7.0.1

Comment: it's the last version

Comment: but if i put it in a init class?

Comment: I've tested your code, and it builds fine. The problem must be somewhere else, did you paste the function in the timeElapsed class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91619/discussion-between-marcoc-and-dejan-skledar).